# FlourineFX rtmp ssl

Tags: c#, rtmps

I'm trying to connect to an `rtmps` server using C# and FluorineFX.

I'm doing this using this code

```
netConnection = new NetConnection();

netConnection.OnConnect += onConnect;
netConnection.NetStatus += netStatus;

netConnection.ObjectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
Console.WriteLine(netConnection.PlayerVersion = "WIN 10,1,85,3");
netConnection.Connect("rtmps://example.com:2099/");
```

example.com is replacing the real url in this example.

But this code only gives me an exception stating that:

```
System.UriFormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format
```

the FluorineFX webpage states that it supports rtmps, so i would think that would be the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a github repo that adds RTMPS support into FlourineFX

https://github.com/epicvrvs/FluorineFXMods

All you need to do is follow the instructions in the top and compile it.